# VSCode - how to use VSCode to debug in Flash and Android?

Tags: android, flash, visual-studio-code, haxe, haxeflixel

I am a ***"real newbie"*** and want to learn about programming.
I got a trouble with the debug option inside VSCode. My question is:

**how to use *"VSCode"* to *"debug"* in *"Flash and Android"*?**

i have already tried to debug. But my debug option only has HTML5 :( so i dont know how to debug in flash or android.
will you please teach me how? :)

[VSCode Debug Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqpjO.jpg)

Comment: oh forgot to give explanation, i am now learning about HaXe language to make a game. the IDE i use is VSCode but when i tried to debug. it only has HTML5 option. i want it to debug using flash and debug inside android phone. anyone know how?

Comment: So no one know? or maybe no VSCode programmer in stack overflow?

Comment: _**uh 2 days already.. i think this place is not for VSCode programmer and no vscode programmer here.. also maybe no haxe programer here.. :(**_

Answer (score 0):

> ***[solved in haxeflixel forum by Gama11](http://forum.haxeflixel.com/topic/310/how-to-install-vscode-haxe/8)***